# Why am I having trouble writing to an array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to read from a file, it's contents are formatted as such:

```
0010:0020:0030:0400:stringUpTo50Chars
```

I've opened the file with fopen(), and I want to copy the contents of the file to an array called records set up with a struct which has the following format:

```
struct structure{
int first;
int second;
int third;
int fourth;
char fifth;
};
```

The array was declared with:

```
struct packet *records;
```

I've been trying to use fgets() along with strtok() and atoi() to read from the file and put the data - separated by colons - into the records array but can't get it to work properly. See below.

```
while(i<100)
{
  fgets(data, 66, fp);

  records[i].first= atoi(strtok(data, ":"));
  records[i].second= atoi(strtok(NULL, ":"));
  ...
  records[i].fifth= strtok(NULL, ":");

  i++;
}
```

Most lines of code work as expected and store the correct values. However if anyone could explain why any of the following issues are occuring it'd be appreciated.

A) Two of the lines from my data source are incorrectly read and return what appears to be a integer representing a memory location rather than a =< four digit value e.g. 840970506 instead of 12 or 0012. This only happens for six values, three each on two lines.

B) All of the data in records.fifth appears to be overwritten by the most recent value for fifth i.e records[1].fifth should be string1 records[2].fifth should be string2 but all values in records[i].fifth are string100. Printing this also causes a crash after a few lines.

C) Putting fclose(fp); generally causes my program to crash, occasionally it gets past it but mostly it doesn't. I opened the file earlier with:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(&sourceFile,"r");
```

&sourceFile is a user set file name containing the data to be read:

```
const char sourceFile;
scanf("%s", &sourceFile);
```

Removing the "&" causes a crash.
D) free(records); to free the memory space allocated for records causes a crash.

E) return 0; at the end of task main() also causes a crash.

For C, D and E commenting out the line(s) tends to allow the code to finish but it still occasionally crashes. CodeBlocks 13.12 isn't giving me any build messages to work with and I have no idea what to do. Any help with any/all of my problems would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you allocate memory with `malloc` for `records`? For question C) Check `fopen` for being `NULL`. And how is `sourceFile` declared?

Comment: The fifth field in the struct you declare holds a single character, why do you think you can fit `stringUpTo50Chars` in it? You need to declare either a char* or char array of suitable size and allocate memory or use strcpy

Comment: 1) `66` small ? 4+1+4+1+4+1+4+1+50=70 (+newline+NUL). 2)  `records[i].fifth= strtok(NULL, ":");` : `fifth` is `char`. change to `char fifth[51];`, `strcpy(records[i].fifth, strtok(NULL, ":");`

Comment: 3) `fp = fopen(&sourceFile,"r");` maybe `fp = fopen(sourceFile,"r");`

Comment: 4) `const char sourceFile;` only allows one character-long filenames. (And it's not a zero-terminated C-string as `fopen` expects.) You want `const char sourceFile[FILENAME_MAX];` (or a numeric constant for whatever your max filename length is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:

Did you allocate memory for your data with

```
records=malloc(100 * sizeof *records); // place for 100 data sets
```

As next, you can manually set all the structure elements with a default value to see if the value comes from the file io or it is the value as before in the memory.

```
for ( int x=0; x<100; x++) { records[x].first=0; ... }
```

Your Point D)
Do you try to free a single element of an array like

```
free( &records[7] );
```

If so, this is wrong! You can only free such memory you have allocated with malloc. As described above, you can/have maybe allocated the memory with one malloc. If so, you have to free all of them in one free call!

I think you did wrong allocation of memory which results in a lot of crashes everywhere you access this not allocated memory. So please show a bit more of your code!

And as a hint: Please simply use a debugger where you can see that your prog files your data memory peace wise. It is often not easy to find an error if you think about your prog in a different direction than the compiler do :-)

One of you structure elements can only hold a single char:

```
char fifth;
```

You can not store a string there. If you want to store up to 50 chars use:

```
char fifth[50+1]; // +1 for the '\0' at the end of the string
```

Also the line

```
fopen(&sourceFile,"r");
```

looks a bit crazy. What is `sourceFile`? If it is:

```
const char *sourceFile="file.xyz";
```

you have to use:

```
fopen(sourceFile,"r");
```

Comment: &sourceFile is a user-set name of the file with data in it, set via scanf() edited question to explain. I'll go over my memory allocation and will try initialising the array with zeros. Went through the suggested changes and it now works as intended. Many thanks.